# how to keep exif data when using resize option in liipimaginebundle

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle, zikula

I am using Zikula with a modulestudio generated module.

The configuration of liip is the following:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: "%kernel.root_dir%/../"
                cache_prefix: "web/imagine/cache"
    loaders:
        zikula_root:
            filesystem:
                data_root: "%kernel.root_dir%/../"
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_thumb: # sample
            jpeg_quality: 90
            png_compression_level: 7
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
                background: { size: [124, 94], position: center, color: '#000000' }
        zkroot: # sample using zikula root
            data_loader: zikula_root
            jpeg_quality: 90
            png_compression_level: 7
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: inset }
        # add more filters as required for your personal application
```

The modulestudio generated code where the file is shrinked is here:

```
$isImage = in_array($extension, $this->imageFileTypes);
if ($isImage) {
    // check if shrinking functionality is enabled
    $fieldSuffix = ucfirst($objectType) . ucfirst($fieldName);
    if (isset($this->moduleVars['enableShrinkingFor' . $fieldSuffix]) && true === (bool)$this->moduleVars['enableShrinkingFor' . $fieldSuffix]) {
        // check for maximum size
        $maxWidth = isset($this->moduleVars['shrinkWidth' . $fieldSuffix]) ? $this->moduleVars['shrinkWidth' . $fieldSuffix] : 800;
        $maxHeight = isset($this->moduleVars['shrinkHeight' . $fieldSuffix]) ? $this->moduleVars['shrinkHeight' . $fieldSuffix] : 600;
        $thumbMode = isset($this->moduleVars['thumbnailMode' . $fieldSuffix]) ? $this->moduleVars['thumbnailMode' . $fieldSuffix] : ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;

        $imgInfo = getimagesize($destinationFilePath);
        if ($imgInfo[0] > $maxWidth || $imgInfo[1] > $maxHeight) {
            // resize to allowed maximum size
            ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
            $imagine = new Imagine();
            $image = $imagine->open($destinationFilePath);
            $image->thumbnail(new Box($maxWidth, $maxHeight), $thumbMode)
                  ->save($destinationFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

My webhosting has enabled the php extension for exif.

My question:

Is it possible to keep the EXIF data inside the jpg file if it becomes a new thumbnail file? Or must it be the original file which has to be shrinked?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This has been solved by reading out EXIF data before creating the thumbnail image.

Comment: A code example showing what you did would be very helpful.

Comment: Here are the relevant code parts:  
  
1. [`readExifData` method](https://github.com/zikula-modules/News/blob/master/MU/NewsModule/Helper/Base/AbstractUploadHelper.php#L306-L341)  
2. [`readMetaData` method](https://github.com/zikula-modules/News/blob/master/MU/NewsModule/Helper/Base/AbstractUploadHelper.php#L250-L304)  
3. [the processing code](https://github.com/zikula-modules/News/blob/master/MU/NewsModule/Helper/Base/AbstractUploadHelper.php#L173-L208)

Comment: That works if the image is available locally, but if you're using Flysystem to upload to s3, I don't think it will work.  It seems reasonable that liip would add it.